# Advise on this . My code has some blocker.i am getting the error 'object required'

Tags: vb6

I am using the functions below.In the first one i have parsed the node of xml and its value using MSXML. similar func fr other xml.i want to use two nodevalues and highlight it.i tried something.but i am getting error in the line highlighted(****) as 'Object Required'.your quick reply will help me more.

Public Sub DisplayNode1(ByRef Nodes1 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, _
   ByVal Indent1 As Integer)

some lines

```
  RichTextBox2.Text = Space$(Indent) & xNode1.ParentNode.nodeName & _
        ":" & xNode1.NodeValue 

        difference
```

some lines

```
Public Sub difference() 

Dim a As IXMLDOMText 

Dim b As IXMLDOMText

a.NodeValue = xNode.innertext  'i get erroe in line    

b.NodeValue = xNode1.innertext           

If StrComp(a, b) > 0 Then  

a = vbRed  

b = vbRed 

End If
```

please help me soon.

Comment: xNode is not defined in difference(), and it isn't being passed into the method, so are we missing some global variable code? Please include all pieces of the applicable code. Based off of what I see, it looks like you are never calling CreateObject on the activeX objects for `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot that is potentially wrong with this.

- xnode isn't declared anywhere in your code sample
- Neither a, b, or xnode are explicitly set anywhere in your code sample
- Unless xnode is a form/module/global level variable then it will be out of scope in the Difference procedure
- It's not shown but I'm guessing that you don't have Option Explicit set in your code or by default

You'll need to address these points first before you can get anywhere with this code.